# DOM not loaded before jQuery attempts to modify it even with events binded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a mobile app with Cordova+Ionic+angular.js frameworks and I am encountering some troubles to execute jQuery actions when the application is fully loaded.
I've tried many things, such as launching the functions with a button and it works, the events 'deviceready' or 'document.ready' are also triggered at app loading and it displays an alert.
So I assumed it comes from the content itself, I think it isn't loaded when jQuery tries to select it and so it return in the console :

```
[context: document, selector: "#listeTraitements", jquery: "1.11.2",
 constructor: function, toArray: function…]i
```

I've defined all my scripts in the head and I can't provide you with fiddles because It would work as it should. So I'll join extract of code.

Thanks for your help, at your disposal for further informations.

HTML

```
<ion-view title="navTitle">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <h2> {{navTitle}}</h2>
        <br/>

        <div id="listeTraitements">I want to append text here!
        </div>

        <button id="nouveauTraitement"  class="button button-block button-outline  button-positive">
            Ajouter un nouveau traitement
        </button>

        <div >
            <input id="nomTraitement" type="text" class="test" placeholder="Nom du traitement"/>
            <button id="ajoutMedic" class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round test" ui-sref="rechercheMedic" onclick="stockNomTraitement()"></button>
            <div>
                <button id="affichTab" onclick="time()">Time</button>
                <button id="affichTab" onclick="Ajout()">Ajout</button>
                <button id="delete" onclick="Supp()">Click !</button>
                <div id="Affichage">
                    <ion-list>
                        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                            Hello, {{te.nomTraitement}}!
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Javascript

```
listMedocs = function(){

    alert('hello');
    $('#listeTraitements').append('FTG');
    console.log("");

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    listMedocs();
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    listMedocs();
},true);
```

EDIT SOLUTION :

Thanks shakib, indeed, it was because the view wasn't fully loaded.

I had to add in my controller this code :

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function(){
    iamreadytowork(); random function that need a fully loaded view.
});
```

Comment: It might be that device is ready but the view is not loaded yet. Try placing the code in `$ionicView.loaded` event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to append a string of text to

```
    <div id="listeTraitements">I want to append text here!
    </div>
```

Try

```
 $('#listeTraitements').html('FTG');
```

instead, or create a new div/text element, and append that.

I hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks shakib, indeed, it was because the view wasn't fully loaded.

This is the solution.
I had to add in my controller this code :

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function(){
    iamreadytowork(); random function that need a fully loaded view.
});
```